# Developing a Flutter app when no backend is available

Tags: flutter, mocking, frontend

In my team I'm responsible for writing a mobile app for making ticket reservations; it's also the first biggish project I'm doing in Flutter. The problem is, at this point, no backend for the application exists yet. All I know is how the API will look like. In order to run the application I created a fake/mocked service which I use instead of the "true" service.

```
class FakeEventsService implements EventsService {
  @override
  Future<List<Event>> fetchEventsList() async {
    var json = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/api/events.json');
    var events =
        Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () => eventFromJson(json));

    return events;
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to deal with this problem? (I know that http client can be mocked in the tests, but I want to run the entire application.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and edit it accordingly , hope you find the solution:

```
  List<Event> eventList = [];

  Future<List<Event>> getEventsList() async {
    final response =
        await http.get(Uri.parse('Put the Api url here'));
    var data = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      for (Map i in data) {
        eventList.add(Events.fromJson(i));
      }

      return eventList;
    } else {
      return eventList;
    }
```

Comment: There's no API url, since the API doesn't even exist at this point at all

Comment: Can you brief me more about the question, so i can help you in the best way i can